# pytest.mark.parametrize seems to only be able to xfail an expected exception

Tags: python, exception, pytest

When parametrizing tests that raise an expected exception, I have been using the following form:

```
import pytest

class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

class AnotherException(Exception):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'error',
    [None,
     pytest.mark.raises(SomeException('the message'),
                        exception=SomeException),
     pytest.mark.raises(AnotherException('the message'),
                        exception=AnotherException),
     pytest.mark.raises(Exception('the message'),
                        exception=Exception),
     ])
def test_mark_raises(error):
    if error:
        raise error
```

Please note that I have installed the pytest-raises package.  Ok, so this works, but I have noticed recently that it is raising a deprecation warning:

```
RemovedInPytest4Warning: Applying marks directly to parameters is deprecated, please use pytest.param(..., marks=...) instead.
```

Ok, that's fine.  We'll update the parametrize list.  But this has been problematic.  pytest.param has a 'marks=' argument, but passing in pytest.mark.raises, doesn't work.  The only way I have found to use exception handling within pytest.param (that actually seems to work at all) is the following:

```
import pytest

class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

class AnotherException(Exception):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'error',
    [None,
     pytest.param(SomeException('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(exception=SomeException)),
     pytest.param(AnotherException('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(exception=AnotherException)),
     pytest.param(Exception('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(exception=Exception)),
     ])
def test_mark_raises(error):
    if error:
        raise error
```

Ok, so this does seem to work, sort of.  But instead of passing the tests, it is xfailing them.

I do not like this.  If I am expecting a test to raise a
particular exception and it does in fact raise the exception,
then I would consider the test to have passed, not 'xfailed'.

And if I am inspecting a bunch of pytest results (1500+ in some cases),
it is visually more work to identify which tests are xfailing
because they expect some kind of failure condition, and which ones
are xfailing because they are not implemented yet (or some other reason
that would indicate we need to fix something).

I don't like getting a bunch of warnings, but I also want tests that correctly show that they passed.  Is there anyone that knows the proper construct to use with pytest.param in the case of expected exceptional behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether to answer my own question or simply update the question.  Since the answer is a bit verbose, I opted to put it here.

pytest-raises release 0.10 now supports the behavior I was looking for.  You can now set up your exception parameters in the following way:

```
import pytest

class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'error',
    [None,
     pytest.param(SomeException('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.raises(exception=SomeException)),
     ])
def test_mark_raises(error):
    if error:
        raise error
```

This is a bit more verbose than the previously accepted practice of putting the mark directly into the parametrize list, but it works as expected, and the deprecation warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable warnings in the output, you can use --disable-warnings flag.

You are using xfail to raise exception when you are not expecting the tests to fail. You should use pytest.raises for raising exceptions - [link](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/pytest_raises.html) . If you want to use markers for raising exceptions, you should use custom markers and write your own test collector. 
Example of conftest.py:

```
import pytest

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    envmarker = item.get_marker("passwithex")
    if envmarker is not None:
        pytest.raises(ErrorName)
```

Test code:

```
import pytest

class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

class AnotherException(Exception):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'error',
    [None,
     pytest.param(SomeException('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.passwithex),
     pytest.param(AnotherException('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(exception=AnotherException)),
     pytest.param(Exception('the message'),
                  marks=pytest.mark.xfail(exception=Exception)),
     ])
def test_mark_raises(error):
    if error:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Although not exactly the answer, it did provide some much needed insight (posting my answer below, as it is a bit verbose).  I just wanted to mention that the passwithex approach didn't quite work for me.  It seems that pytest.raises(ErrorName) was returning a RaisesContext object and apparently doing nothing with it.  So the raised exception in the test function was still failing.  Maybe it was something I missed?  Again, thank you for taking the time.